# Angular - http request receives null, not sure if it's frontend or backend issue

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a authentication in Angular 9, so I'm make a rest api with java spring boot version 2 and I add a rest api java security and JWT.
I have this method above:

```
   return this.http.post<any>(`${this.endpoint}/login`, user)
     .subscribe((res: any) => {
       localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.token)
       this.getUserProfile(res._id).subscribe((res) => {
         this.currentUser = res;
         this.router.navigate(['user-profile/' + res.msg._id]);
       })    
     })
 }
```

this method return "res is null", I don't know what try to fix it.

Comment: did you try add console.log before `localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.token)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you was able to get `res` even though it is `null`, it means your frontend doesn't have a problem but your backend issue.

You have to check your backend (maybe your authentication endpoint returns nothing)

Comment: Hello yash, I'm learng java and angula. I'm using basic java security and your endpoin is "/login". I'm test my api with postman and return token and http 200.

Comment: you should have `res` with the token then, did you try add console.log before localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.token)?

Comment: I add console.log(res), the console return nothing.

Comment: I get method post, http 200 Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtYXJjb3NAaG90bWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1OTY1OTUxNzl9.ycZk6wQPz08OhXC6RYXctq-j7sdcOa-1dta0pQHhekblakawdT8wPYFA4wy7dIIxsDZRYqSe7LdCv2NgfUeaRQ

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
 *